# Which is the better combination? spring boot with kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-kafka

i am designing realtime kafka consuming job, and considering between spring boot batch and spring boot.

- kafka version : 2.11-1.1.1
- jdk : 1.8

which is better?

1. spring boot batch + kafka
2. spring boot + kafka

and please tell me why :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking to create job and manage through spring cloud data flow further, go with the #1 and if you use case is to just keep consuming the kafka message when recieved to kafka topic, use spring boot and spring kafka. It totally depend on your use case.